# Get images from Document Directory not file path Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, nsdocumentdirectory

This is how I saved the images

```
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="MMMM-dd-yyyy-ss"
    let currentFileName = "\(format.string(from: Date())).img"
    print(currentFileName)

    // Save Images
    let fileMgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPath = fileMgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let imageFileUrl = dirPath.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)



        do {

            try UIImagePNGRepresentation(returnedImages)!.write(to: imageFileUrl)

            print("Image Added Successfully")

    } catch {

        print(error)

        }
```

Below is code  I am using to retrieve images, But I am getting the URL instead of the image file to populate tableview.  Any help would be appreciated

```
   let fileManager = FileManager.default
   let imageUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) [0].appendingPathComponent("img")

   print("Your Images:\(imageUrl)")
```

Comment: I think you can use UIImage(contentsOfFile: yourUrl) to get the image from this url

Comment: @ 3stud1ant3 thanks for your answer, but when I do this as you suggested: let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl). I am getting error "  Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'"

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry I added the error above

Comment: Ok, use this imageUrl.path instead of imageUrl

Comment: Whenever I do this: let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)! it's crashing saying that " unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" that meams I am not retiriveing the images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153648/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-iam-wayne).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply because your image's name is invalid. Use the debugger to find the exact value of `imageUrl`, I bet it's something like this `.../Documents/img`. What you want is more like `.../Documents/Sep-04-2017-12.img`

You'd have to store `currentFileName` in the view controller so you can reference it later.

Also, your naming strategy is pretty fragile. Many images can end up sharing one name.

---

If you have a folder full of images, you can iterate on that folder to get back the `img` files:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "img" {
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile; imageURL.path) {
        // now do something with your image
    } else {
       fatalError("Can't create image from file \(imageURL)")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. You're correct, that's the value I am getting. However, whenever the image are saved, they'ew saved Like this "September-04-2017-11.img". I am trying to retrieve the images in a separate view controller.

Comment: Then [iterate through](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414584-contentsofdirectory) your Documents folder and select all the `.img` files. Or you can pass the array of file names to the second controller

Comment: Whenever I try to iterate through documents folder I am getting "The folder “.img” doesn’t exist."

Comment: You are iterating at the wrong level. Remove the `appendingPathComponent` call

Comment: Getting the same result, maybe I am doing something wrong. Would you mind showing me, how you would go about doing this?

Comment: thanks for your help, I am getting the right url paths. However, I am trying to convert the url to get the images, but can't get that to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the path (`/path/to/file.img`) and the URL (`file://path/to/file.img`). Apple is trying to kill of the path and move everyone to URL. It's baffling why they don't make an initializer that takes a URL for `UIImage`. You can convert a URL to path by calling `imageURL.path`

Comment: @ Code Different thank you very much, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 func getImage(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("apple.jpg") // saved image name apple.jpg
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
            self.lockbackImageview.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
        }else{
            print("No Image")
            self.lockbackImageview.image = UIImage.init(named: "1.jpg")
        }
    }
```