# Can not load images from `Documents` directory on device

Tags: ios, swift, image, webview, ios12

On simulator this works.
Here is the path I printed while saving an image: 
`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31912F79-EB94-4DB1-84B8-68C7368B9160/Documents/t123t.jpg`

And this is img tag in html which should load image into webView(worked fine on simulator):

`img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31912F79-EB94-4DB1-84B8-68C7368B9160/Documents/t123t.jpg">`

As I can see everything looks ok here, I thought problem should be in the path, I removed part `file://` from `img src` but it didnt help me.

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045948/get-images-from-document-directory-not-file-path-swift-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solved***
For some reason, images in `Documents` weren't accessible this way with loading html from string. I needed to create a `html file` in `Documents` folder to be able to read images from that folder. 
So, **html and images(resources) need to be in the same folder**.
Code that didn't work:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath))
//html is a string.
```

Code that works:

```
 let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
 let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
 let filename = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("index.html")

 do {
     //html is a string
     try html.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
      } catch {
            //...
     }
 webView.loadFileURL(filename, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsDirectory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay firstly the path you mentioned

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31912F79-EB94-4DB1-84B8-68C7368B9160/Documents/t123t.jpg
```

Folder with random string (Inside Application) always changes after reopening the app.

Apple implemented this for security purpose.

```
            let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
            let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true).first
            let path: String = paths!
            //path has address of document directory and we need address of tmp directory where pictures are stored

            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("\(url)")
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
```

This worked for me in my first project when I got stuck in same problem.

Hope I helped you :)

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks but I cannot see how can this help me. All my images should be downloaded into Documents folder and then img source(html) should read from that folder and the images would be loaded into webView.

Comment: As I said earlier due to Apple's security implementations the parent folder of Documents directory always change on every launch of app, so my code will search for the document directory regardless of where it is placed.
If you want URL then imgURL will give you URL and if you want image itself then the image variable will have your image.